# Azure Drawing Tools

Tags: azure, architecture, diagram

I'm Looking for a drawing tool that allows me to design Architecture diagrams like this.

Please advice

[image: Solution Architecture Diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Microsoft Azure Cloud and AI Symbol / Icon Set in (svg) format from following location and use them.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=41937

If you are using Visio, download the Azure stencils from following.
https://github.com/sandroasp/Microsoft-Integration-and-Azure-Stencils-Pack-for-Visio